# Referencing Sitecore 10.0 Update 1 Nuget

Tags: nuget

Currently only Sitecore 10 Initial Version (Sitecore 10.0.0) and Sitecore 10.1.0 are in the list coming from Sitecore nuget.

[image]

For example this dll for Layout Service has version 6.0.0 for Sitecore 10.0.0 but 6.1.1 for Sitecore 10.0.1 (Sitecore 10 Update 1).

We can add it of course via good old way to add dll to solution and reference that but I want to use Sitecore nuget.

**Is there any possibility to reference Sitecore 10.0.1 (Sitecore 10.0 Update 1) dlls via nuget?**

Comment: We can ask this to support but till then I think you can create your own Nuget package for this version

Comment: Like this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25750/creating-nuget-package-with-sitecore-items-dll-and-config